# How to print the second lowest repetitive element by count in Scala

Tags: list, scala

Input: list = [23, 23, 25, 34, 34, 32, 34]

Here 34 occurs 3 times, whereas 23 occurs 2 times.
I need to print the second lowest value. In this case output should be 23

I'm not able to figure out how I can pass the list as an argument and get the required output.

Comment: I won't give the answer but a couple of advice: use `groupMapReduce` to compute the count of the elements. Then use `toList` + `sortBy` to get the values sorted by their counts, and finally use `lift` to safely try to access the second element.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not aware of groupMapReduce, but will try to find out

Comment: The **Scaladoc** is your friend: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html